# Block inside elements BEM-methodology

Tags: html, css, bem

Depending on the documentation of BEM you should not use Elements within elements.

That makes sense to me, because a block contains elements wich cannot be outside that block.
But can an elements contain a block? So that the block inside that element cannot be outside that element.

The official Website of BEM uses this. But I always thougt the idea of blocks is, that you can put it anywhere on the page without any dependencies.

Here is the DOM from the official Website 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3R1V.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually BEM allows elements inside elements.

And of course BEM allows blocks inside elements but **not** in the way they can't also be used outside that element.

Feel free to keep blocks inside or outside elements. It's just ok.

Comment: Okay? In the documentation there is a chapter called:
Why does BEM not recommend using elements within elements (block__elem1__elem2)? So I am confused?

Comment: It's not about nesting in DOM, it's about resembling DOM structure in class naming which is really not useful. So `<div class="block"><div class="block__elem1"><div class="block__elem2"></div></div></div>` is ok (and `block__elem1__elem2` is not).